# Deshabilitar botones Atras y Siguiente pagination

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, bootstrap

he realizado una subpagina donde he incluido un pagination para moverse entre los datos de la tabla, pero tengo un problema: Donde muestro los primeros datos es en listaproductos?page=1 o listaproductos.php pero el cuando estoy en la primera pagina me deja darle al button de "Anterior" y me lleva a ?page=0 y me da un error ya que no existe esa pagina. ¿Alguien sabría como deshabilitar los botones de "Anterior" en la primera página y "Siguiente" en la última página? Muchas gracias a todos.
Mi codigo:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/addproductos.css?ver=5">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sidebar.css?ver=6">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css?ver=4">
<style>
#main-information {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3%;
    padding: 20px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
} 
.content-header {
    padding: 10px .5rem;
}
.well {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 19px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
.pagination > li > a
{
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<link rel="icon" href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/423/423080.svg" >
    <title>LISTA DE PRODUCTOS - PABLOWEBDEV.COM</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php
session_start();
require 'lib/checklogin.php';
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php
    require 'lib/header.php';
    require 'lib/sidebar.php';
    ?>
    <div id="main-information">
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Lista de productos</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Lista de productos</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Index</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div> <!--- content header --->

<?php
require 'logic/conexion.php';
$limite=10;
 $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
 $start=($page - 1) * $limite;

$result=$conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos LIMIT $start, $limite");
$customers=$result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$result1=$conexion->query("SELECT count(id) AS id FROM productos");
$custcount=$result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$total=$custcount[0]['id'];
$pages= ceil($total/$limite);

$previous= $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
?>

<div class=container>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio compra</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio venta</th>
      <th scope="col">Link</th>
      <th scope="col">Sección</th>
      <th scope="col">Ganancia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach($customers as $customer) : ?>
    <tr style="color: black;">
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['id']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['nombre']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['precioinicial']?>€</td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['precioventa']?>€</td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['link']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['seccion']?></td>
            <td style="background-color:#DEE0E3;"><?= $customer['ganancia']?>€</td>          
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div> <!---- TERMINA CONTAINER ---->
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item" >
      <a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $previous;?>">Anterior</a>
    </li>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++) : ?>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></a></li>
    <?php endfor;?>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="listaproductos.php?page=<?= $next;?>">Siguiente</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav> 


    </div>  <!-- TERMINA MAIN INFORMATION --->
</div> <!-- TERMINA WRAPPER --->

</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta manera te inhabilitará el elemento con la clase CSS de bootstrap llamada "disabled".

Espero que te ayude mi respuesta:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li class="page-item <?=  $_GET['page'] == 1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
            <a class="page-link" href="index.php?page=<?= $previous; ?>">Anterior</a>
        </li>
        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) : ?>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?page=<?= $i; ?>"><?= $i; ?></a></li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <li class="page-item <?= $_GET['page'] == $pages ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
            <a class="page-link" href="index.php?page=<?= $next; ?>">Siguiente</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Explicación breve:

Compara si la página actual es igual a la página 1, si es así añade la clase disabled que inhabilitará el elemento y no te dejará pulsarlo.

```
<li class="page-item <?=  $_GET['page'] == 1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
```

Compara si la página actual es igual al total de páginas, si es así añade la clase disabled que inhabilitará el elemento y no te dejará pulsarlo.

```
<?= $_GET['page'] == $pages ? 'disabled' : '' ?>"
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! funciona

Answer (score 0):

tendrias que hacer una condicion pj:

```
if($_GET['page'] > $tu_variable_de_paginas_actules || $_GET['pag'] <= 0){
   //Lo envias al pag=1
   header('Location: index.php?pag=1');
}
```

osea si el valor es verdadero y es mayor a tus paginas actuales (mostrar registris que no existen lo envias al index y si es verdaderos y es menor a 0 o 0 negativo lo envias al index

para deshabilitar el anterior y siguiente seria el mismo mecanismo, validando tus variable de pag actual y siguiente o anterior

Comment: Tienes un problema de comillas al inicio

Comment: Gracias BetaM, editado

Comment: Me realiza un bucle infinito de redirects

Comment: fijate si lo estas colocando bien a tu script y las variables sean validas, por ejemploi y por lo q ue llego a entender de lo tuyo la variable $tu_variable_de_paginas_actules que te puse en mi ejemplo, seria tu variable $pages

Comment: if($_GET['page'] > $pages || $_GET['page'] <= 0){
  //Lo envias al pag=1
      echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.location.href='listaproductos.php';
    </script>");
}

Comment: Y no funciona.., me sigue dejando entrar a listaproductos.php?page=0, he probado cambiando la variable por $page, $pages y nada..

Comment: eso que te pase es para que por URL no pongan valores negativos o si no existe el valor te lleva a tu pag=1

Con repecto a deshabilitar los botones tenes que hacer una condicion, por ejemplo si $pages < 0 $_GET['pages] >= $pages escribis el html para que no tenga link y visceversa

Comment: entonces que puedo hacer?